# Java regex match stack overflow

Tags: java, regex, stack-overflow

```
Pattern eqPattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)([a-z0-9\\_\\.]*) eq \"(((\\\\\")|[^\"])*)\"([\\s]*.*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

This is my regex.
When I try to match a long string, I got stack overflow.
The pattern will match something like
column1 eq "abc" and column ne "abc";
(\\\")|[^\"]): to skip " in inside "".
I want to ask how to rewrite this to prevent stack overflow.

Comment: What would be the sample that overflows ?

Comment: The test case is long and I cant give it here. Something like . user eq "1200 repeated s"

Comment: No problem, probably a bunch of escaped stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to remove the alternation from the regex.
That can be done like this, which uses the unrolled loop instead:

`"(.*?)([\\w.]*) eq \"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^\"\\\\]*)*)\"(\\s*.*)"`

Raw and Expanded

```
 ( .*? )                       # (1)
 ( [\w.]* )                    # (2)
 [ ] eq [ ] 
 "
 (                             # (3 start)
      [^"\\]* 
      (?:

           \\ [\S\s] 
           [^"\\]* 
      )*
 )                             # (3 end)
 "
 ( \s* .* )                    # (4)
```

Comment: Great. It works. Can you please give some explanation of ([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^\"\\\\]*)*)? Quite hard to understand.

Comment: Sure. This optional clause  `[^"\\]*` matches non escapes nor quotes greedily. In the last part which is optional, there can only be an escape _anything_ which is required, followed by the optional clause again `[^"\\]*` where these are wrapped into a repeating optional group. The result is that there is no need for an alternation, in which Java executes on the stack. In the original regex, the first check was an escape anything which probably sent it to the alternation a lot. You probably could get away with this as well `"((?:[^"\\]|\\[\S\s])*)"`